# Which data structure can handle 2d line segments

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have huge list of 2d line segments. I want to find nearest line segments for a given segments and then to store in a vector. So, I want to do this for each and every line segment so that I know nearest line segments for any line segments. All my line segments are in vector form that is, I know both end point coordinates. So in my data line-number, begin (x,y,z), end(x,y,z) are there.

For obtaining the line segments, I want to check the distance between the line segment and end point of another line segment ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment)).

I think there might be some data structures that all these things happen and give a vector of vector line segment numbers or some other way to recognize proximity line segments. I know kd-tree (k-nearest) can do the similar thing. But it is for point data.

I was trying to figure out this with opencv r-tree function. But as I do not have any experience of using r-tree I was not able and I am confused now because it says about a classifier and has a training phase. But for my case, I feel I don’t want such things to follow.

If anyone knows any function or codes or library to do this type of thing, please let me know.

Comment: How big is "huge"? What sort of system do you have to solve the problem on? [Might make a difference if it's a mobile phone or a 1000-machine cluster with 64GB and 16 cores per system]

Comment: @Mats Petersson: in my data, nearly 40,000 line segments are wit me. its 1gb ram with 1.4 ghz dual core machine.

Comment: And do you have a time-limit (e.g. needs to do this every 1/50th of a second or some such)?

Comment: What about a KD-Tree? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498949/data-structure-for-fast-line-queries

Comment: @Mats Petersson: Not that much. but i wish to do this data structures as handling data might be much easier when doing codes as I know sepeteate proximity line seg. lists

Comment: @Justin: Actually, I mentioned kd-tree in my post (as k-nearest), But as far as i know it is defined for point data. (even the above link also said the same)... so I was struggling to do this with kd-tree as it was too hard for me, then i am now looking for some other options

Comment: @niro OK, you never mentioned KD-Trees by name, so I didn't know. You can use a KD-Tree with line segments which is part of the link I sent. Here is the direct link to the comment stackoverflow.com/a/1498995/950252 but it is non-trivial.

Comment: @Justin: true, i tried with that way..(the kd-tree) it is hard and not the best option. from that page also they mentioned r-tree.

Answer (score 0):

While OpenCV doesn't have a data structure for line segments, the following works well enough.

```
struct LineSegment{
  Point2f a,b;
};
```

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt , Why? Is there a C++ convention I'm ignoring? I copied and pasted this out of my C++ program. Thanks!